# Heteroscedasticity/autocorrelation in panel spatial models

Tags: references, panel-data, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, spatial

We have panel data and we are interested in a simple panel spatial model:

$$Y_{it} = \alpha + \rho WY_{it} + \beta X_{it} + \mu_i + \epsilon_{it}$$

The maximum likelihood fixed effects estimator is what we need.

1. How do we model heteroscedasticity in the ML function?
2. How about autocorrelation?
3. Can someone provide a helpful reference?

Comment: The spatial network modeling literature is one of the best sources for  work related to your question re autocorrelation in panel data. For instance, Isaak, Ver Hoef and Petersen, *Spatial Statistical Network (SSN) Models for Data on Stream Networks: Background, Theory and Applications* is one example ... https://acwi.gov/monitoring/conference/2016/2_wednesday_may4/H3/SSNM%20overview_NWMC_Isaak2_secure.pdf  Also, Tom Snijders (at Oxford) publications on longitudinal, multilevel network analysis (SIENA software) should be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into these papers. Sorry for the late reply, I have just realised that someone replied to my post.